# How compare in Microsoft sql server 2012 management studio sql with collation character set encoding

Tags: sql-server, ssms, collation

I've create SQLQuery with "Select Top 1000 Rows" in microsoft sql server 2012 management studio "Object Explorer":

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[UserInfo]
```

Then add at the end of query:

```
WHERE [tp_Title] = 'Sandra Vasiliauskaitė'
```

Query returns correct record set.
Then add at the top of query:

```
USE [WSS_Content]
GO
```

Query returns no rows. Then undo last modify (Ctrl+Z) to:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[UserInfo]
WHERE [tp_Title] = 'Sandra Vasiliauskaitė'
```

Query returns no rows

PS

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
-
Lithuanian_CI_AS
```

Microsoft server 2012 with Current language for non-Unicode programs:
**Lithuanian (Lithuania)**

Comment: You really want to avoid any dependence on collation at least for character representation when you go beyond the common ASCII subset. Use a Unicode literal (`N'Sandra Vasiliauskaitė'`). Collation then still influences the result of the comparison, but at least not the ability to even represent the value.

Comment: Note that the server default collation is only relevant as a shorthand for the collation of the system databases (`master`, `tempdb`). The collation of string literals will be the collation of the database you're currently in, which need not be the same as the server collation. You can use `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to refer to that without spelling it out, but keep in mind that the collation of the current database need not be the same as the collation of the column (which was set at creation).

Comment: Thank you. It works. `WHERE [tp_Title] COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI = 'Sandra Vasiliauskaitė'` it works too. But not with DATABASE_DEFAULT or Lithuanian_CI_AS

Comment: Yes, the collation of `tp_Title` need not be `Lithuanian_CI_AI` (or the database collation, whatever it is). You don't normally see this when comparing with a literal because a literal will conform itself to whatever the collation of the other side of the comparison is. You do need to take care when using a parameter, though, because the collation of a parameter is the database default collation. Regardless of the collation, using a Unicode literal is almost always a good idea, otherwise you make things even more complicated.